# Bootstrap alert button design is off and doesn't close when clicked

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I am experimenting with Bootstrap, the bootstrap alert button is somehow not working at all. All I did was copy the code from Bootstrap :
[image]

But the page is showing this? The design of the button is off, and it's not working(doesn't close). I checked everything: `alert-dismissible` is there, the button has `data-dismiss = 'alert'`, but somehow it's not working. The script I included is the Bootstrap bundle version.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You changed a small part of the example: your `data-dismiss` should be `data-bs-dismiss` and the class on the button should be `btn-close` instead of `close`:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

[Documentation about dismissing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/#dismissing)

On close inspection, I noticed that your alert is a [Boostrap 4 alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/alerts/#dismissing). In your example, you use the CSS and JavaScript from Bootstrap 5, where dismissible alerts should look like the example above.

Comment: I realized I was using the Bootstrap 4 documentation instead of v5!! Thanks alot!

Comment: data-bs-dismiss worked for me